# not entering if statement, calling a controller method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

so I am making this little quiz web app and the way I do it is by calling a controller method with the line

```
<li><%= button_to @current_question.answer1, request.base_url + '/answer/1' %></li>
```

/done the same for the other 3 options/

which seems to work as the controller method gets called:

```
def isAnswer
    @current_question = Question.find(session[:current_question])
    if params[:id] == @current_question.correct_id
        session[:answers_right] += 1 
    end
    session[:current_question] += 1
    render 'session'
end
```

Here is my route line:

```
post 'answer/:id' => 'sessions#isAnswer'
```

However the problem is that I never enter the if statement no matter which option I click. Also I tried saving the params[:id] and  @current_question.correct_id in the session[] and printed them to see if they are both 2(in my test case) and they were.

Comment: It's a best practise in ruby to name predicate methods with a trailing question mark `?` and use `snake_case` https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming `isAnswer` should be more like `is_answer?`

Comment: well the method doesn't return anything but sure I understand what you mean, for now though I am trying to fix my problem with counting the correct answers

Comment: whats in your params hash?

`puts params`

Comment: well, I tried showing the params[:id] element and it seems to be just as I intended it to be its the number of the option that I clicked. could it be that the :id elements is passed as a string and I am comparing it to an integer

Comment: okay, yes that was the problem, I just remembered that you pass the id as a string

Comment: you can post an answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that session[:id] was the string '1' and not the integer 1. So I fixed it by calling Integer(session[:id]) and then comparing it to the correct_id.